# Sublime2: Unable to change translate_tabs_to_spaces setting

Tags: sublimetext2

I want HTML files to have a 2 space indent so I've updated my Packages/User/html.sublime-settings file as follows:

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "erb", "html"
    ],
   "tab_size": 2,
   "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
}
```

However, whenever I save a file as an HTML file (i.e. with the .html extension) the Tab Size remains 4.

What else do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Turn autodetection of indentation off just by adding one more line to your `Packages/User/html.sublime-settings` file:

```
"detect_indentation": false
```

You can open settings file for current syntax via *Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific - User*